# Extracting point information from raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I'd like to work with climate data available from [here](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/frost_days/) and extract values of certain locations (for which I have lat and lon).

This is what I've done so far:

```
library(SDMTools)
library(raster)

test <- raster(read.asc.gz("C:/.../grids_germany_annual_frost_days_1951_17.asc.gz"))

> test
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 866, 654, 566364  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 3280415, 3934415, 5237501, 6103501  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 13, 288  (min, max)
```

[image]

Now I figured I might be looking for the `extract` function but:

```
> extract(test, c(3634415,5603501))
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
```

Adding the `buffer` argument results in:

```
extract(test, c(3634415,5603501), buffer=1000)
Error in .cellValues(x, y, ...) : unused argument (buffer = 1000)
```

Could you explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can extract values from the raster?

Comment: Looks like you may be using UTM coords.  Try `projection(test) <- "+proj=utm +zone=17" `(Note change UTM zone 17 to your zone). http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/extract

Comment: No, that won't affect the results at all in this case, since the y query has no metadata about the projection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `y` argument to `extract` must be 2D, i.e. a matrix or a Spatial* object (or whatever).

Your `y` query is just an atomic numeric vector, and so is intepreted as two cell numbers (**i.e. indexes**), which is why you get two missing values since they are way out of bounds (cue debate about whether that kind of out of bounds should trigger a different kind of "missing").

Do this:

```
extract(test, matrix(c(3634415,5603501), ncol = 2))
```

This might seem like an obscure behaviour localized to `raster`, but it's the same with other standard R functions like `plot`. Essentially your dimensionless vector is treated in a "vectorized" way.  If you give plot a non-dimensional vector (it's really *not* 1-D in the sense of an array, this is a bugbear in R and other languages) it actually adds its own index for the X-axis.

I wonder what extract and plot do with actual 1-D arrays with degenerate dimensions . . .

Comment: The problem is in using "c" rather than "cbind". You can use cbind(3634415,5603501) and avoid coercing to a matrix.

Comment: That is kind of irrelevant, the effect is the same. cbind gives a matrix

Comment: Not irrelevant, efficient. cbind(x,y) rather than matrix(c(x,y), ncol = 2)